# HP SAS Expander 12Gb max storage limitations

Tags: raid, storage, hp, lsi

Is the max storage limitation stated in HP's documentation a real limitation or not?

I currently have 48TB (8x 6TB in a raid 6) and I just purchased a Norco RPC-4224 and 8 additional drives to double my capacity to 96TB

I was planning on using a [HP 12Gb SAS Expander (769635-B21)](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04346272.pdf)  along with my [LSI 9260-8i](http://www.avagotech.com/products/server-storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-sas-9260-8i) but in the spec sheet is says that that the SAS expander is limited to:
"Up to 90TB of total storage with 15 x 6TB 3.5" SATA MDL HDD"

Is this true?

I've read about a lot of people purchasing this product to use with the Norco RPC-4224 and I haven't seen many of them using SAS drives.

Is there really a limit to 90TB and 15 SATA drives?

I've been reading and searching over at hard forums and haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to really know. The expander is a basic PCIe card. If you see anything on the HP spec sheet, it's likely geared towards an audience who plan to use the expander with HP server equipment.

Your use case is not who they're writing the documentation for. However, I don't see any reason you'd run into problems with your setup.

That said, I have one of these expanders in one of my HP storage servers. It *should* work for what you're doing.

[image]